# Groovy, insert node after current node

Tags: arrays, groovy, insert, each

I'll try my best to explain the situation.

I have the following db columns:

```
oid - task - start - end - realstart - realend
```

My requirement is to have an output like the following:

```
oid1 - task1 - start1 - end1
oid2 - task2 - start2 - end2
```

where task1 is `task`, task2 is `task + "real"`, start1 is `start`, start2 is `realstart`, end1 is `end`, end2 is `realend`

BUT

the first row should always be created (those `start/end` fields are never empty) the second row should only be created if `realstart` and `realend` exist which may not be true.

Inputs are 6 arrays (one for each column), Outputs must be 4 arrays, something like this:

```
#input oid,task,start,end,realstart,realend
#output oid,task,start,end
```

I was thinking about using something like `oid.each` but I don't know how to add nodes after the current one. Order is important in the requirement.

For any explanation please ask, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment and understanding that you don't want (or cannot) change the input/output data format, here's another solution that does what you've asked using classes to group the data and make it easier to manage:

```
import groovy.transform.Canonical

@Canonical
class Input {
    String[] oids = [ 'oid1', 'oid2' ]
    String[] tasks = [ 'task1', 'task2' ]
    Integer[] starts = [ 10, 30 ]
    Integer[] ends = [ 20, 42 ]
    Integer[] realstarts = [ 12, null ]
    Integer[] realends = [ 21, null ]

    List<Object[]> getEntries() {
        // ensure all entries have the same size
        def entries = [ oids, tasks, starts, ends, realstarts, realends ]

        assert entries.collect { it.size() }.unique().size() == 1,
                'The input arrays do not all have the same size'

        return entries
    }

    int getSize() {
        oids.size() // any field would do, they have the same length
    }

}

@Canonical
class Output {
    List oids = [ ]
    List tasks = [ ]
    List starts = [ ]
    List ends = [ ]

    void add( oid, task, start, end, realstart, realend ) {
        oids << oid; tasks << task; starts << start; ends << end

        if ( realstart != null && realend != null ) {
            oids << oid; tasks << task + 'real'; starts << realstart; ends << realend
        }
    }
}

def input = new Input()
def entries = input.entries

def output = new Output()

for ( int i = 0; i < input.size; i++ ) {
    def entry = entries.collect { it[ i ] }
    output.add( *entry )
}

println output
```

Responsibility of arranging the data is on the `Input` class, while the responsibility of knowing how to organize the output data is in the `Output` class.

Running this code prints:

```
Output([oid1, oid1, oid2], [task1, task1real, task2], [10, 12, 30], [20, 21, 42])
```

You can get the arrays (Lists, actually, but call `toArray()` if on the List to get an array) from the `output` object with `output.oids`, `output.tasks`, `output.starts` and `output.ends`.

The `@Canonical` annotation just makes the class implement equals, hashCode, toString and so on...

If you don't understand something, ask in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

IF you need an "array" whose size you don't know from the start, you should use a `List` instead. But in Groovy, that's very easy to use.

Here's an example:

```
final int OID = 0
final int TASK = 1
final int START = 2
final int END = 3
final int R_START = 4
final int R_END = 5

List<Object[]> input = [
        //oid,     task, start, end, realstart, realend
        [ 'oid1', 'task1', 10, 20, 12, 21 ],
        [ 'oid2', 'task2', 30, 42, null, null ]
]

List<List> output = [ ]

input.each { row ->
    output << [ row[ OID ], row[ TASK ], row[ START ], row[ END ] ]
    if ( row[ R_START ] && row[ R_END ] ) {
        output << [ row[ OID ], row[ TASK ] + 'real', row[ R_START ], row[ R_END ] ]
    }
}

println output
```

Which outputs:

```
[[oid1, task1, 10, 20], [oid1, task1real, 12, 21], [oid2, task2, 30, 42]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful solution, but in my case every attribute of the list is an Array, all of the same length, so I have 6 arrays in total, does it work the same?

Comment: Why do you get the data in such a weird format? Anyway, I will edit the answer to try to help.